# Logic Error in Java Program

Tags: java

Writing a program that reads in numbers from a text file and tests them to see if they are prime or not. Text file consists of the following numbers: 98, 76, 84, 69, 92, 83, 88, 90, 72, 66. The first number, 98 is not prime, but then the second number (76) should come out as Prime. My printed out results show all the numbers being Not Prime which is not true.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignFive_FileRead {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

int number; 
int calc = 0;
int i = 2; 

File myFile = new File("Numbers.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

// Check to see if file exists
if (!myFile.exists()) {
  System.out.println("Error: file cannot be found");
  System.exit(0);
} else {
  System.out.println("File has been found, starting operation...");
}

// Reading numbers from text file
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
  number = inputFile.nextInt();

  // Begin calculation to see if number is prime
  while (i <= number / 2) {
     if (number % i == 0) {
        calc = 1;
     }
     i++;
  } // End second while loop

  if (calc == 1) {
     System.out.println("Number: " + number + " is Not Prime!");
  } else {
     System.out.println("Number: " + number + " is Prime!"); 
  }

} // End first while loop

} // End main 
} // End public class
```

Comment: Why would you think that 76 is prime?

Comment: You never reset `calc` to `0` when reading a new number. Also calc should be a `boolean`, its more suited.

Comment: You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means. Even numbers cannot be primes.

Answer (score 5):

There is a bug in your code (I just spotted it).

But the big error is in your testing methodology.

You say that `76` is a prime number.  It isn't.  `76` is `38 x 2`, and that means it is not prime.  (Indeed, any positive number that is even and larger than 2 is not prime ...)

In fact, `83` is the only prime number in that list.

Answer (score 1):

Init calc whenever you read a number

```
// Reading numbers from text file
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    number = inputFile.nextInt();

    // Begin calculation to see if number is prime
    calc = 0;
    while (i <= number / 2) {
    // [...]
```

Answer (score -1):

You should reset both i and calc every time you come out from second while loop. I have fixed it by using the following code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignFive_FileRead {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

int number; 
int calc = 0;
int i = 2; 

File myFile = new File("input.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

// Check to see if file exists
if (!myFile.exists()) {
  System.out.println("Error: file cannot be found");
  System.exit(0);
} else {
  System.out.println("File has been found, starting operation...");
}

// Reading numbers from text file
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
  number = inputFile.nextInt();

  // Begin calculation to see if number is prime
  while (i <= number / 2) {
     if (number % i == 0) {
        calc = 1;
     }
     i++;
  } // End second while loop

  if (calc == 1) {

     System.out.println("Number: " + number + " is Not Prime!");
  } else {
     System.out.println("Number: " + number + " is Prime!"); 
  }
  calc = 0;
  i=2;

} // End first while loop

} // End main 
} // End public class
```